# GAE SDK for Python 2.5

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, python-2.5

I have an existing app that uses the deprecated Python 2.5 and the deprecated master/slave datastore. According to the docs, I must migrate the datastore to HRD before I can upgrade to Python 2.7. Before I can migrate my M/S datastore to HRD, I need to do some work on the app and test it using the dev server.

However, I upgraded to the most recent version of the SDK (1.8.6), and it does not support Python 2.5. Somebody else encountered this problem and learned that the latest SDK that supports Python 2.5 by default is Python SDK 1.7.5. From where can that be downloaded? Or, is there a way I can make the SDK 1.8.6 work with Python 2.5?

Comment: GAE no longer supports Python 2.5 since March 2013, http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/python-25-thanks-for-good-times.html. Starting January 2014, GAE won't let you run Python 2.5 code anymore. Consider upgrading your app to Python 2.7, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27

Comment: Mr. Reichart, observe that I said I cannot upgrade my app to Python 2.7 until I have migrated my datastore from M/S to HDR, and I cannot do that until I have done some work on my app while still using Python 2.5--thus my question about where to get a Python SDK that works with Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1.8.6 SDK, there's an `old_dev_appserver.py` that works with Python 2.5. That'll help you along as you migrate.

Comment: Do you have to use old_dev_appserver.py from a command line, or is there a way to tell the launcher to use it? Or, does running it bring up a UI like the launcher?

Comment: I don't know. I always use the command line, and never use the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Dave W. Smith gave me the answer but I didn't know how to implement it until I made a discovery that maybe most people already know, But in case it might be helpful to somebody, I will tell it here:

I do all my GAE/Python/Flex development work in Eclispe, except that I used the launcher for local testing and deploying. (I am command-line adverse.) I discovered that using the PyDev Eclipse plugin it is easy to set up a "run configuration" (under the PyDev "Run" menu) whereby you can set up command line parameters, etc. and run any python program from within Eclipse. I now use that facility for running dev_appserver.py (and when needed for my Python 2.5 app, old_app_devserver.py). I no longer have a need to use the launcher. I also set up a PyDev run configuation to deploy my app and performing various appcfg.py functions (vacuum indexes, etc.).